# Doxygen support for C++11 template aliases (the 'using' syntax)?

Tags: c++, c++11, doxygen

I'm using doxygen 1.7.1 to generate documentation for some C++ 11 code and it seems to be ignoring my template aliases.

For clarity, here's an example of a template alias:

```
template<class T>
using ResultOf = std::result_of<T>::type;
```

It also fail to pick up more tradition typedefs written with the cleaner new using syntax:

```
using PredicateOne = std::function<bool(string)>; // Doxygen doesn't catch this

typedef std::function<bool(string)> PredicateTwo; // but does catch this.
```

Is there a setting or later release that will properly document these aliases?

Comment: You're asking whether a version released in early 2010 supports C++11?

Comment: @BenVoigt C++11 used to be called C++0x and there is support for it in tools much earlier than 2010. Even leaving that aside, I'm asking about what I need to do to get a tool that I use to do what I need. I included "upgrade" in the possible fixes, and I included the version that I'm using to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[version 1.8.2](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/changelog.html) supports new usage of `using` keyword

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I'm pretty sure that doxygen hasn't added support for that yet, but it's probably on the todo list and the more people ask the developers nicely, the sooner it will appear.

The version you have, 1.7.1, is quite old and has no chance at all, no matter what settings you use.