# 'using' C++11 keyword in doxygen

Tags: c++, c++11, doxygen

I have some C++11 code that looks something like this:

```
using Vertex = std::array<float, 3>

using Triangle = struct TriangleStruct {
    Vertex v1, v2, v3;
};
```

However, doxygen does not detect `Vertex` or `Triangle` as a struct, or even as a type. If I do the old style `typedef struct ...` it does work though.

Is this format supported by doxygen? Is there perhaps a workaround to get this to show up?

I'm using doxygen 1.8.8 on OS X.

Comment: It looks like it was supposedly [fixed in version 1.8.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534024/doxygen-support-for-c11-template-aliases-the-using-syntax)

Comment: The linked doxygen bug appears to only reference template aliases, not 'plain' aliases, is there a difference? I'm definitely running doxygen 1.8.8: 
 doxygen -v gives
1.8.8

Comment: bug is here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672372

Comment: Am I right that doxygen 1.8.11 still ignores non-template aliases (like Vertex in question)?

Comment: As mentioned in earlier comments, there was an older bug that's already fixed. However, as doxygen has its own parser, it's not that surprising that it doesn't cover all cases. Best to log a new bug for this issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues